# NullPointerException when removing component from jpanel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to remove a component from a jpanel but it keeps giving me a `NullpointerException`. I am trying to remove a component from the jpanel and then add a label in its place.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Minefield extends JFrame
{
private final int ROWS= 3;
private final int COLS=3;
public JButton[][] grid ;
private GridBagConstraints c;
private JPanel display;
public Minefield()
{
    grid = new JButton[ROWS][COLS];
    JPanel display = new JPanel();
    add(display);
    display.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
     c = new GridBagConstraints();  
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL; 
    MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
    for(int row=0;row<ROWS;row++)
    {
        for(int col =0;col<COLS;col++)
        {
            grid[row][col]=new JButton(""+row+","+col);
            c.gridx = col;  
            c.gridy = row;
            display.add(grid[row][col],c);
            grid[row][col].addMouseListener(handler);
        }
    }

}
private class MouseHandler  implements MouseListener
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
        for(int row=0;row<ROWS;row++)
        {
            for(int col =0;col<COLS;col++)
            {
                if(event.getSource()== grid[row][col])
                {

                    remove(grid[row][col]);
                    display.revalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){}
}

}
```

And here is the error it gives me

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Minefield$MouseHandler.mouseClicked(Minefield.java:48)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Line 48 is `display.revalidate()`.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Answer (score 4):

You have declared two variables named `display`:

```
public class Minefield extends JFrame
{
    // ...

    private JPanel display;
    public Minefield()
    {
        grid = new JButton[ROWS][COLS];
        JPanel display = new JPanel();
        // ...
```

This second variable is local in the constructor. When you call `display.revalidate()`, you are accessing the `private` field which has not been initialized.

To fix the problem, you can just remove the declaration:

```
display = new JPanel();
```

Better, yet, you can initialize the field inline:

```
public class Minefield extends JFrame
{
    // ...
    private JPanel display = new JPanel();
```

Then remove the line `JPanel display = new JPanel();` from the constructor.

**Note**

You are doing more work than necessary in `mouseClicked()`. You do not need any for loop. You can just use `event.getSource()` directly for the same effect:

```
private class MouseHandler  implements MouseListener
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
    {
        remove(event.getSource());
        display.revalidate();
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){}
}
```

After closer examination, I see that both this and your original code have a flaw that might affect other parts of your application that aren't shown here (or that you haven't written yet). The `mouseClicked()` function will remove a button from being displayed, but you still have a reference to the button in `grid`. This might cause problems if you try to access the buttons in the `grid` array and assume that they are rendered in the `JPanel`.